# Unable to debug in rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have following simple program with current state of rstudio as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

When I called `fun1()` on console, it results in following screen:

[image]

I was expecting it to highlight line 1 `a<-5` with yellow color showing green arrow on left as `line 143` in this digram:

[image]

When I click `Next (F10)` in Console window, it looks like this:

[image]

So it seems that, it has step throught line 2 `a<-5` and created a variable `a` as its shown in Environment window, but still it does not highlight the current line to be executed with yellow color nor it shows the green arrow pointing the line. Whats wrong here?

I am running portable version of RStudio 0.99.903 on Windows 7 64bit and RStudio is configured to use 32 bit R 3.3.0. I am new to RStudio. Primarily used eclipse.

Comment: Your file is not saved (red color).

Comment: good observation, but nope, it was some whitespace which turned that file name title red...also saving did not work...it was indeed issue with 32 bit R as mentioned by Jonathan in the answer...switched to 64 bit R and things started working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. Starting at R 3.3.0, an internal R change broke RStudio's debugger for 32-bit R. There are two ways to get around the problem:

1. Use the preview version of RStudio, which includes a fix for this problem.
   https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/
2. Use the 64-bit version of R, which shouldn't have the problem.

If you use the preview, send us some feedback and let us know whether it addressed your issue!